# Set a date by weeknumber with carbon

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

I know I can *get* the week number with [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) by calling `$my_date->weekOfYear`. Is there a way to *set* a date by week number?

I mean is there something for initializing a date to the first day of the 3rd week of 2017 year?

I can initialize a date to the start of the year, I think it's a good start but I don't know what to do next:

```
$a = (new \Carbon\Carbon('2017-01-01'));
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe `setISODate` takes care of this:

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$date->setISODate(2017,3);
echo $date->startOfWeek();
```